# Linux Kernel Programming: interruptible_sleep_on vs wait_event_interruptible

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a linux device driver (on linux kernel version 5.10.11-v7l+) and I am using O'Reilly's Linux Device Drivers, second edition. In the section on blocking I/O, it explains the difference between `interruptible_sleep_on` and `wait_event_interruptible` and how the former is interruptible by a signal and the latter is interruptible by evaluating a condition. For my driver, I have an ISR that signals to a thread that the device is ready to be read from and it seems to me that `interruptible_sleep_on` would be preferable as it just sends a signal to the wait queue and doesn't need a condition variable to be set by the ISR and then cleared by the thread (which, at least it seems to me, would require another access control method for that variable).

But, `interruptible_sleep_on` is no longer in the kernel (at least in my version) and `wait_event_interruptible` is the only option. My question is: is there a way to duplicate the behavior of `interruptible_sleep_on` with `wait_event_interruptible` and essentially eschew using a condition variable and just rely on the signal being pushed to the wait queue?

Relevant code:

```
static int data_ready = 0;

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void* dev_id)
{
    static unsigned long flags = 0;

    local_irq_restore(flags);

    data_ready = 1;

    wake_up_interruptible(&dataint);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int data_thread_fn(void* param)
{
    allow_signal(SIGKILL);

    while(!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        wait_event_interruptible(dataint, data_ready == 1);

        data_lock(); //lock to share with main thread

        data_buffer(); //read data from device

        data_unlock(); 

        wake_up_interruptible(&databuffer); //tell poll that data is ready

        data_ready = 0;

        if (signal_pending(data_thread))
            break;
    }
    
    do_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So currently your thread is sleeping using `interruptible_sleep_on(wq)` and your ISR is waking up the thread just invoking `wake_up_interruptible(&wq)`, is that correct? And I suppose the thread does this in a loop and gets continuously woken up by the ISR, right? Would you mind adding some minimal piece of code that gives an idea about what is going on and the context surrounding those calls?

Comment: The 2nd edition of Linux Device Drivers is really quite old. The [third edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is also old, but slightly less so (LDD3 was written for 2.6.10, some changes have probably been done since). LDD3 also contains an equivalent example of "Advanced Sleeping" in chapter 6 (and also documents `interruptible_sleep_on` as Ancient history). This is largely because it introduces a possible race between the sleeper and waker.

Comment: hey @MarcoBonelli I added in the relevant code sample that will compile based on what I laid out. What you wrote is how I would ideally like it, but, as mentioned, this will not work on my version of the kernel.

Comment: And @Hasturkun, thank you for some context on the linux kernel and Linux Device Drivers. I knew that ```interruptible_sleep_on``` was removed in newer versions, but wasn't sure when and wasn't sure how to properly implement something similar with ```wait_event_interruptible```.